# tensor product of power sets and power set of cartesian product

Tags: measure-theory

I have to prove the following:

Let $X,Y$ be countable sets. Show that $\mathcal P(X) \mathcal  \otimes \mathcal P(Y) = \mathcal P(X \times Y)$.

I found a similar question with an answer here [Sigma algebra on a Cartesian product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349213/sigma-algebra-on-a-cartesian-product) but I'm not sure if in my case, $\mathcal P(X) \otimes \mathcal P(Y)$ is a product $\sigma$-algebra and thus defined as
$\mathcal P(X) \otimes \mathcal P(Y) = \sigma \left( 
\{B_1 \times B_2 | B_1 \in \mathcal P(X), B_2 \in \mathcal P(Y) \} \right)$.

I know that the power set of a set is a $\sigma$-algebra. So, it would make sense that $\mathcal P(X) \otimes \mathcal P(Y)$ is a product $\sigma$-algebra as defined above.

Can somebody confirm this or explain it if it's not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\{(x,y)\}= \{x\}\times \{y\}\in \mathcal{P}(X) \otimes \mathcal{P}(Y)$ and thus if $K \subseteq X \times Y$, we have
$$K = \bigcup_{(x,y)\in K} \{(x,y)\}$$
where we note that $K$ is countable (since $X$ and $Y$ are countable) and thus the union is again in $\mathcal{P}(X)\otimes \mathcal{P}(Y)$. Hence,
$$\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)\otimes \mathcal{P}(Y)$$
and the other inclusion is trivial.

Comment: thank you! Is it true that $\mathcal P(X) \otimes \mathcal P(Y) = \sigma \left( 
\{B_1 \times B_2 | B_1 \in \mathcal P(X), B_2 \in \mathcal P(Y) \} \right)$ is a product $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: @syphracos Yes definitely. The definition of a product $\sigma$-algebra is exactly the following: if $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ are measurable spaces, then the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ is exactly $\mathcal{M}\otimes \mathcal{N}:= \sigma(\{A \times B: A \in \mathcal{M}, B \in \mathcal{N}\})$, i.e. $\mathcal{M}\otimes \mathcal{N}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the "measurable rectangles". In your example, $\mathcal{M}= \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mathcal{N}= \mathcal{P}(Y)$ (where we note that power sets are trivially $\sigma$-algebras). Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again! Would it maybe be possible that you show $\mathcal P(X) \otimes \mathcal P(Y) \subseteq \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ ? I know you said that it's trivial but I can't see why

Comment: @syphracos The right hand set are all subsets of $X\times Y$...